# Shortest path A to B taking in specific points

Tags: graph, path, shortest

I have a set of N points for which I have coordinates (Ordnance Survey grid references). I want to start at point A and finish at point B and visit all the other points along the way, with the least travel time.

I have acquired Mathematica 9 but I am struggling with it. I tried  FindShortestTour but that wants to take me back to my starting point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a variation of "Traveling Salesman Problem".

The suggestion is to induce FindShortestTour function to include BA edge into the tour and then remove BA from the solution: manually set BA edge being, say, -1000; find the shortest tour (check that BA is in the solution!) and finally remove BA edge: add 1000 to compensate -1000 you've initially set.

Comment: I don't understand your solution - all I have is cordinates. Here's an example.

pts = {{569314, 190118}, {568027, 188950}, {572307, 188527}, {573703, 
   188113}, {574352, 193316}, {577823, 186280}, {580669, 
   187367}, {570874, 206069}}

The first point is the start and the last point is the end. I want to rearrange the other points to minimise the total path length.

Comment: use distance function argument when call FindShortestTour: all distances except BA (and AB) are standard Euclidian sqrt((xi - xj)**2 + (yi - yj)**2), while BA (and AB) is a constant small number, say -1000